# Pkg.add("Ijulia") chmod not defined

Tags: julia

Newbie trying to get going with IJulia on Debian Jessie, and am stuck with an error. Don't know how to interpret the message, and not actually sure on what to do next.

The beginning is all ok :

---

```
julia> Pkg.init()
    INFO: Initializing package repository /home/sybs/.julia/v0.3
    INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl

julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
    INFO: Cloning cache of BinDeps from git://github.com/JuliaLang/BinDeps.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of Compat from git://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of Conda from git://github.com/Luthaf/Conda.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of Dates from git://github.com/quinnj/Dates.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of HttpCommon from git://github.com/JuliaWeb/HttpCommon.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of IJulia from git://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of JSON from git://github.com/JuliaLang/JSON.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of Nettle from git://github.com/staticfloat/Nettle.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of SHA from git://github.com/staticfloat/SHA.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of URIParser from git://github.com/JuliaWeb/URIParser.jl.git
    INFO: Cloning cache of ZMQ from git://github.com/JuliaLang/ZMQ.jl.git
    INFO: Installing BinDeps v0.3.21
    INFO: Installing Compat v0.7.11
    INFO: Installing Conda v0.1.9
    INFO: Installing Dates v0.3.2
    INFO: Installing HttpCommon v0.1.2
    INFO: Installing IJulia v1.1.8
    INFO: Installing JSON v0.5.0
    INFO: Installing Nettle v0.2.2
    INFO: Installing SHA v0.1.2
    INFO: Installing URIParser v0.0.7
    INFO: Installing ZMQ v0.3.1
    INFO: Building Nettle
    INFO: Building ZMQ
    INFO: Building IJulia
    INFO: Installing Jupyter via the Conda package.
    INFO: Downloading miniconda installer ...
    --2016-02-23 14:43:46--  http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-3.9.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
    Résolution de repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)… 23.21.205.0, 174.129.25.1
    Connexion à repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)|23.21.205.0|:80… connecté.
    requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 200 OK
    Taille : 23531867 (22M) [application/octet-stream]
    Sauvegarde en : « /home/sybs/.julia/v0.3/Conda/deps/usr/installer.sh »

    home/sybs/.julia/v0.  48%[=========>            ]  10,86M  16,4KB/s   eta 14m 14s/home/sybs/.julia/v 100%[=====================>]  22,44M  13,8KB/s   ds 29m 43ss
```

---

Then I get a "chmod not defined" error :

---

```
INFO: Installing miniconda ...
===============================[ ERROR: IJulia ]================================

chmod not defined
while loading /home/sybs/.julia/v0.3/IJulia/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 35

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: IJulia had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /home/sybs/.julia/v0.3
 - build a package and all its dependencies with `Pkg.build(pkg)`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
INFO: Package database updated
```

---

I opened up the build.jl file and scroll before and after line35 and got this :

---

```
if jupyter_vers < v"3.0" || dirname(jupyter) == abspath(Conda.SCRIPTDIR)
    info("Installing Jupyter via the Conda package.")
    Conda.add("jupyter")
    jupyter = abspath(Conda.SCRIPTDIR,"jupyter")
    jupyter_vers = prog_version(jupyter)
    jupyter_vers < v"3.0" && error("failed to find $jupyter 3.0 or later")
end
info("Found Jupyter version $jupyter_vers: $jupyter")

#######################################################################
# Warn people upgrading from older IJulia versions:
try
    juliaprof = chomp(readall(pipeline(`$ipython locate profile julia`,
                                       stderr=DevNull)))
    warn("""You should now run IJulia just via `$jupyter notebook`, without
            the `--profile julia` flag.  IJulia no longer maintains the profile.
            Consider deleting $juliaprof""")
end

#######################################################################
# Install Jupyter kernel-spec file.
```

---

So, what shall I do next ? chmod a+x build.jl ? then Pkg.build("IJulia") ?

Comment: Which version of Julia are you using?, could yo share the output of `versioninfo()`?, the line that calls `chmod` is from `Conda`: https://git.io/v2nGy

Comment: The version output : Julia Version 0.3.2
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_LAPACKE DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Piledriver)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.5

Comment: I got it fixed by going into the .julia/v0.3/Conda/debs/user/installer.sh, then render it executable  : chmod a+x installer.sh, then execute it.

Comment: But I still haven't figured out how to get iJulia working. $ ipython notebook --profile julia gives the following message : Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: Use `jupyter notebook` from the shell or `using IJulia; notebook()` from inside Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#running-the-ijulia-notebook Now they are Jupyter notebooks not IPython notebooks: https://try.jupyter.org

Answer (score 1):

`Conda.jl` author here. I do not have enough reputation to comment, so here is an answer.

Conda is tested on the latest julia 0.3, which is 0.3.12, and works there. So a possible fix would be to update your Julia version to either that or 0.4.

You can also try to install it manually, by making it executable and then running `./installer.sh -b -f -p $HOME/.julia/v0.3/Conda/deps/usr/`.

Comment: My Julia version is :Julia Version 0.3.2
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
  WORD_SIZE: 64
           Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)

Comment: I have already tried running the installer.sh, also tried using "using Julia; notebook()." .. with error messages.  ipython3 notebook triggers Jypyter, so I 'm also trying to figure out how to access Jupyter directly without using Conda if it's possible... oh by the way, the installer reloads Miniconda all over again. Why does it need to do that ?

Comment: Can you update Julia to a more recent version ? That would be the easiest thing to do. 

If you can not, `rm -rf ~/.julia/v0.3/Conda`, and then run `Pkg.add("Conda")` from julia prompt. If it fails, try running `./installer.sh -b -f -p $HOME/.julia/v0.3/Conda/deps/usr/`

Comment: Which "recent" version à you referring too ? Doesn't "apt-get install julia" do just that ? Out of curiosity, I saw somewhere that the "lastest" version is 0.4. But it's on sid. So, tried that, had some fun, crashed. Installed a new clean Jessie. Installed ipython3. Installed Anaconda3. Installed julia. Pkg.init(), Pkg.update(), Pkg.add("IJulia") etc. etc.

This loop is infinite !

The amazing thing is I've got an old laptop (Dell Inspiron) with Jessie installed (32bit), and on this laptop, it found Jupyter during the installation. On the 64bit machine, it didn't find Jupyter...  ?

Comment: By recent I am refereing to either 0.3.12 (the last version 0.3) or 0.4 (the last "stable" version). Julia is a fast moving target, so you should pick binaries from http://julialang.org/downloads/ instead of relying on your package manager.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found that out on https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia, and tried to compile the v0.4, but had some problems because some tools are missing (like gfortran, etc..). Am working to try to solve this... Thanks.